# is it possible to upload achievement definitions

Tags: google-play-games

I would like to define achievements in my own database, then upload them to google play. this would give me more control on how to manage my achievements. is this possible? I could not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Apparently not, but that's more of a question for the GooglePlay support team.

Comment: In what way you want to manage your achievements? Have you tried to explore the 'Achievements' tab for your game in the Google Play Develop Console? To learn more on how to implement achievements, follow this link:https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#client_implementations. Here's a sample demo management tools to demonstrate how to manage/unlock Achievements: https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Publishing API](https://developers.google.com/games/services/publishing/) to upload Achievements and Leaderboards.  There is a command line sample in https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools/tree/master/publishing-sample

Answer (score 0):

In uploading Achievements in google play, you may use '*Play games Services Publishing API'*. 
To manage your Achievements, you may use '*OnAchievementsLoadedListener*' this listener called when achievement data has been loaded.

For possible status code, please follow link below:https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/OnAchievementsLoadedListener?hl=en

Here's a sample demo app to demonstrate how to manage Achievements: https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools